# base64 limitations not showing up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, base64

Simple question that I am unsuccessful in finding a simple answer for. I have an image editor as a part of a text editor. After the user is done editing the image they can save it to the server. In order to do this, I have to use base64 decoding on the PHP side. However, when the dataURL info reaches a certain size, the ajax request fails. The thing about it... the size that it starts failing at is less than 1MB. When it is less than that, the ajax sends it and everything works.

I have the site hosted on godaddy. I tried to find "POST" size limitations, but I can't seem to find anything. I have also tried

```
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
```

to see if I can figure out what the limit is set to. But when I run the page, nothing is printed.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Simply running `echo ini_get('post_max_size');` should print the given limit, with the exception of if your host has disabled `ini_get();`. Try turning up `error_reporting`. Also, bear in mind that the base64-encoded data is going to be about 30% larger in size than the original form. That is the price you have to pay to make your data 7-bit safe.

Answer (score 0):

Set `post_max_size = 8M;` with a size of your choice, in php.ini. Otherwise, it could be a problem with what you are trying to decode. The base64 characters must be as follows: http://www.garykessler.net/library/base64.html .

Comment: I set the post_max_size to 96M and it's still doing it. I viewed phpinfo() and it says the max size is 96M, like it should, but it still won't work. 

I added an xrh to the ajax to see if it is working at all. The percentage gets to 100%, but then the file doesn't save. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the php file? But I don't get why it works with a slightly smaller file